# how to eliminate id in url?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have below code in my controller A where there is "ËDIT" link and I want to pass selected column "Id" to another controller B.

**Controller A**

```
response.Rows =
            (
            from item in selectedListAfterPagging
            select new GridEmployeeData()
            {
                id = item.Id,
                cell = new string[] { 
                item.Id.ToString(),
                item.Name,
                "<a href='/Home/MenuThree/"+ item.Id + "' title='Edit'>Edit</a>"
                }
            }
            ).ToArray();
```

**Controller B**

```
public ActionResult MenuThree(int Id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This works fine to me except the Url when I click "EDIT" link,

```
http://abc/Home/MenuThree/1
```

The Url contains ID, how to eliminate this?
Or
Any other way to pass ID other than anchor tag, Is there any way to pass data and form link through @Html.ActionLink like views?

Comment: But.... that IS the URL, why would you want + **need** to change it?

Comment: i don't want ID in my Url, clean Url....please have a look again the bottom part of question...thnx

Comment: It' still very unclear what do you want to achieve and why.

Comment: Is the `1` the same as effectively `?1`? Are you talking about passing it as a parameter, such as a query string or form element?

Comment: i simply want to pass my ID value to a different action of a controller and i don't want to show my ID in the URL...apart from anchor tag, any other way?

Comment: hope my question is now clear...

Comment: Unfortunately your question is still very unclear, especially what you refer to as `controllers`. (When replying to a comment, [you need to put the username of the person you're replying to](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), otherwise they are not notified. The owner of the post, in this case you, will *always* be notified)

Answer (score 0):

The only easy way to keep the ID out of the URL is if you use it as an element in a form that posts to the MenuThree action method, in which case you'd have a render a form for each of the IDs, but I'm not sure what you're looking to accomplish by doing so.